# Read links of text file one by one for start_urls in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

links.txt

```
www.link.com/1 | linkname1
www.link.com/2 | linkname2
www.link.com/3 | linkname3
```

My target is to set the "*www.link.com/1*" link for **start_urls** variable and "*linkname1*" for **name** variable. Then my further codes are able to scrape the data from the link "www.link.com/1". then It should process for another line "*www.link.com/2 | linkname2*". I want to carry on the process for thousands of line like these.
My code works only for a single line. It is not working for next line. So my question is how can I loop through for all lines in the text file.

My Scrapy Code:

```
f = open('links.txt', 'r')
listoflinks = [line.strip().split(' | ') for line in f.readlines()]
for pair in listoflinks:
    start_url = [pair[0]]
    name = pair[1]
f.close()

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    allowed_domains = ["link.com"]
    start_urls = start_url;
```

I could try this so far. This code only process for one line. I need to do for thousands of line. Any suggestion/hint would be very helpful.

Comment: Does it only read the first line or the last line?

Comment: interestingly last line ! Good point.

Comment: start_url and name are constantly being overwritten by your loop. Maybe you could start off by doing: `listoflinks = [line.strip().split(' | ') for line in f]`. Then you are certain your list is correct. Then you need to stop overwriting your variables in your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

[scrapy.Spider.__init__](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L26) accept both `name` and `start_url` .

```
class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    allowed_domains = ["link.com"]

with open('links.txt', 'r') as links:
    for link in links:
        url, name = link.strip().split('|')
        spider = LinkSpider(name, start_urls=[url.strip()])
        print 'name: {}, start urls: {}'.format(spider.name, spider.start_urls)
```

Ouput:

```
name:  linkname1, start urls: ['www.link.com/1']
name:  linkname2, start urls: ['www.link.com/2']
name:  linkname3, start urls: ['www.link.com/3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the lines of the textfile and extract the variables `start_url` and `name`, which works fine. But the part of your code that uses those variables is outside of the loop.

Also I assume you want to create one instance of LinkSpider for each line? Then you need to do something like this (even nicer would be to write a constructor that takes the two variables as arguments):

```
class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    allowed_domains = ["link.com"]
    start_urls = None

f = open('links.txt', 'r')
listoflinks = [line.strip().split(' | ') for line in f.readlines()]
for pair in listoflinks:
    start_url = [pair[0]]
    name = pair[1]

    ls = LinkSpider()
    ls.name = name
    ls.start_urls = start_url

    # do something with ls...

f.close()
```

A little sidenote, instead of:

```
for pair in listoflinks:
    start_url = [pair[0]]
    name = pair[1]
    ...
```

you can just write:

```
for start_url, name in listoflinks:
    ...
```